# importing csv file deliminated by tabs into a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I want to import this from a csv file.

```
task_name   time_spent  notes   date    task_number

Worked on hotfrog.  45  Hotfrog started glitching so I moved on to something else.  01/25/2017 02:25    1

falkd   3   adlskfj 01/01/2005 09:40    2
```

and turn it into a one list with dictionaries inside of it to look like this:`

```
self.example_dict_list = 

[{'task_name': 'Worked on hotfrog', 'time_spent': '45', 'notes': 'Hotfrog started glitching so I moved on to something else', 'date': '01/25/2017 02:25', 'task_number': '1'}, {'task_name': 'falkd', 'time_spent': '3', 'notes': 'adlskfj', 'date': '01/01/2005 09:40', 'task_number': '2'}]
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We're glad to help, but you're expected to make an effort to figure it out yourself first. What have you done in an attempt to do so?

Comment: your post makes no sense, where is the value from `time_spent` coming from? where is the value from `notes` coming from?

Comment: I apologize I will fix it. And to Ken White I've been trying for an hour to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, I made a small `CSV` file which looks as such:

```
task_name   time_spent  notes   date    task_number
worked on blah  45  glitching and stuff 1/1/15  2
stuff   40  stuff happened  2/3/16  5
```

Then to convert it to a list of dicts you would do this:

```
import csv

f = 'path_to_file.csv'

with open(f, 'r') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    headers = reader.next()
    dict_list = []
    for line in reader:
        dict_list.append(dict(zip(headers, line)))

dict_list

[{'date': '1/1/15',
  'notes': 'glitching and stuff',
  'task_name': 'worked on blah',
  'task_number': '2',
  'time_spent': '45'},
 {'date': '2/3/16',
  'notes': 'stuff happened',
  'task_name': 'stuff',
  'task_number': '5',
  'time_spent': '40'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is returning this error though...AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: I'm assuming you're in Python 3 then. Change that line to `headers = next(reader)`

Comment: It didn't return properly. This is what it gave: `[{}, {'task_name\ttime_spent\tnotes\tdate\ttask_number': 'Worked on hotfrog.\t45\tHotfrog started glitching so I moved on to something else.\t01/25/2017 02:25\t1'}, {}, {'task_name\ttime_spent\tnotes\tdate\ttask_number': 'falkd\t3\tadlskfj\t01/01/2005 09:40\t2'}, {}]
`

Comment: actually I think it might be an issue on my end

Comment: looks like it's tab separated, change `csv.reader(fin)` to `csv.reader(fin, delimiter = '\t')`

Comment: That worked 99%, but it is giving me an empty dictionary at the beginning, middle, and end of the list `[{}, {'task_name': 'Worked on hotfrog.', 'time_spent': '45', 'notes': 'Hotfrog started glitching so I moved on to something else.', 'date': '01/25/2017 02:25', 'task_number': '1'}, {}, {'task_name': 'falkd', 'time_spent': '3', 'notes': 'adlskfj', 'date': '01/01/2005 09:40', 'task_number': '2'}, {}]`

Comment: that has probably something to do with your input file, code works as intended given the sample you provided. You can just set that list to a variable and then do `dict_list = [i for i in dict_list if i]` and that will remove all empty dicts. Without the actual csv I can't tell you what's the problem.

Comment: yes sorry, I don't do this often thanks for the reminder.